# Can I hook the Reply event in a Thunderbird extension

Tags: xpcom, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

Is there a way add an event handler in a Thunderbird extension that fires when the user clicks "Reply"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In compose_overlay.js:

```
window.addEventListener("compose-send-message", mySendHandler, true);
window.addEventListener("compose-window-init", myReplyHandler, true);

function mySendHandler(evt){
    var msgcomposeWindow = document.getElementById( "msgcomposeWindow" );
    var msg_type = msgcomposeWindow.getAttribute( "msgtype" );

    // do not continue unless this is an actual send event
    if(!(msg_type == nsIMsgCompDeliverMode.Now || msg_type == nsIMsgCompDeliverMode.Later) )
        return;

    //do not continue unless it is a reply action (not a forward)
    var msgType = gMsgCompose.type;
    if(!(msgType == Components.interfaces.nsIMsgCompType.ReplyToSender || msgType == Components.interfaces.nsIMsgCompType.Reply))
        return;

    var origURI = gMsgCompose.originalMsgURI;
    if(origURI == ""){
        return;
    }

    var TBmain = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService().QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator).getMostRecentWindow("mail:3pane");
    var msgHdr = TBmain.messenger.messageServiceFromURI(origURI).messageURIToMsgHdr(origURI);

    //TODO
    //Do something with the msgHdr

}

function myReplyHandler(evt){
    var origURI = gMsgCompose.originalMsgURI;
    var TBmain = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService().QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator).getMostRecentWindow("mail:3pane");
    var msgHdr = TBmain.messenger.messageServiceFromURI(origURI).messageURIToMsgHdr(origURI); 

    //TODO
    //Do something with the msgHdr
}
```

Courtesy: gaurang1988

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=9182225&sid=c81555cc47c06bafde88cadbbd7f7808#p9182225

Comment: Thank you, you made me archieve my goal! :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your goals you could overlay the reply button and get a click event when the user clicked the reply button(s).